# Get position of imageview on layout android

Tags: android, layout, position, imageview

Please help me i want to get position of imageview on a layout.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this with `getLocationOnScreen(int [])`

Comment: not work for me. my image with is in a RelativeLaoyout and it relates with a button from the top and aligns with the right

Answer (score 16):

```
x = imageViewObject.getLeft();
y = imageViewObject.getTop();
```

Hope, it help you!

Comment: didn't work for me. Everything returned zero. (Used with Button, not ImageView, but that shouldn't make a difference.)

Comment: @mathheadinclouds doesn't work for me either. Did you ever get a work around?

Comment: Still no solution? It's 0 for me too

Answer (score 7):

At runtime you can get the location of every `View` object (this includes `Layouts` too) with

Left Position of View Object `getleft()`

Top Position of View Object  `getTop()`

Right Position of View Object  `getRight()`

Bottom Position of View Object  `getBottom()`

Even you can get the location with

`getLocationOnScreen(int [] )`

Answer (score 1):

Position meaning x and y and height and width?

This layout is a view, that view has these properties.

Comment: i want to get current location on view means x and y corrdinate, so that i can animate from this position to that position.

Comment: Look at the methods available in the View class.

Answer (score 0):

the below code works for me to get the original spot i used the global boolean variable `moved` to find the value once in the `onTouch` method `v.getX()` and ...`getY()` gets the value of my `imageView` object I have run this on my apk file on a device and it works perfectly. hope this helps

```
  joystick.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(moved){
                moved = false;
                xOrigin = v.getX();
                yOrigin = v.getY();
                mode.setText(Float.toString(xOrigin));
                challenge.setText(Float.toString(yOrigin));
            }
            mode.setText(Float.toString(v.getX()));
            challenge.setText(Float.toString(v.getY()));
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        xCoOrdinate = v.getX() - event.getRawX();

                    yCoOrdinate = v.getY() - event.getRawY();
                    //mode.setText(Float.toString(v.getX()));
                    //challenge.setText(Float.toString(v.getY()));
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    v.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                    if(v.getX() < xOrigin -50){
                        v.animate().x(xOrigin -50).setDuration(0).start();
                    }
                    else if(v.getX() > xOrigin +50) {
                        v.animate().x(xOrigin +50).setDuration(0).start();
                    }
                    if(v.getY() < yOrigin -50){
                        v.animate().y(yOrigin -50).setDuration(0).start();
                    }
                    else if(v.getY() > yOrigin +50) {
                        v.animate().y(yOrigin +50).setDuration(0).start();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    v.setX(xOrigin);
                    v.setY(yOrigin);
                    mode.setText(Float.toString(xOrigin));
                    challenge.setText(Float.toString(yOrigin));
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```